# visibility issue for copy constructor of base class

Tags: c++, gcc, visibility, copy-constructor

I have a class (let's call it `base` for the moment) that has a protected interface, including protected constructors etc. Some functions of `base` return an instance of `base` by value:

```
class base {
protected:
    base() {}
    base (base const &other) {}  // line 6
    base foo () {
        base ret;
        return ret;
    }
};
```

These functions are wrapped in the derived classes to return the derived type like so:

```
class derived : public base {
private:
    derived(base const &b) : base(b) {}
public:
    derived() : base() {}
    derived foo() {
        derived d(base::foo());  // line 21
        return d;
    }
};
```

To facilitate the conversion from the `base` return type into a `derived` return type, I provide a private constructor in `derived` that handles this.

Compiling this on Centos 5.8 with gcc 4.1.2 produces the following error:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘derived derived::foo()’:
test.cpp:6: error: ‘base::base(const base&)’ is protected
test.cpp:21: error: within this context
```

With gcc 4.6.1 and clang 2.9 on Linux Mint 12, the code compiles file, even with `-Wall -Wextra`, apart from an `unused parameter` warning for `base`'s copy constructor.

I think this could be a compiler bug in gcc 4.1.2, but I was unable to find anything on the net. Has anyone seen this before?

I cannot update the compiler without massive pain. Is there a simple workaround other than making the copy constructor of the base class public?

---

**EDIT** I added `base b;` before line 21 in `derived::foo()`. In that case, gcc 4.6.1 and gcc 4.1.2 complain that the default ctor of `base` is protected, clang 2.9 compiles without warning. This is what David Rodríguez - dribeas said in his comment - the default ctor cannot be called on a different instance of `base`.

---

**EDIT 2** The standard paragraph that seems to apply here is 11.5 [class.protected]. gcc 4.1.2 seems to be correct in refusing my code as incorrect and I wonder why gcc 4.6.1 and clang allow it. See my own answer for a preliminary solution.

Comment: Since MarkB has removed his answer, I will post the main point here: `protected` does not give the derived types access to those members on *any* instance of the base type. You can only access the protected members of your own derived type. I.e. `derived::foo()` can only access the protected members of `base` from `this` or any other `derived` object (including objects whose complete type is itself derived from `derived`)

Comment: Yeah, I read about that too (even looked it up in the standard), and this was also my first idea, but I wonder why both gcc 4.6.1 and clang 2.9. compile this without problems.

Comment: +1 @DavidRodríguez-dribeas eye-opening. I've been under the wrong impression this whole time. Not only that, I was **certain** of the exact opposite.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Well, to most respects, you cannot access the protected members of objects of other types other than yourself, but there is actually a huge whole in the language ([DR 1007](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1007)) that is actually the result of the (in my opinion) *wrong* design decision that was reported back in 2000 ([203](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#203))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preliminary solution is to make `base`'s copy ctor `public`. To disallow copying of `derived` instances using the copy ctor of `base`, the inheritance needs to be `protected` instead of `public`. The resulting classes now look like this:

```
class base {
protected:
    base() {}
public:
    base (base const &other) {}
protected:
    base foo () {
        base ret;
        return ret;
    }
};

class derived : protected base {
private:
    derived(base const &b) : base(b) {}
public:
    derived() : base() {}
    derived foo() {
        derived d(base::foo());
        return d;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that you could try would involve creating a private constructor for derived that constructs it's base by calling the base function:

```
class derived : base {
    struct from_base_foo {};
    derived( from_base_foo ) : base( base::foo() ) {}
public;
    derived foo() {
       return derived( from_base_foo() );
    }
};
```

Comment: Tried it, the error is then emitted for the call to the ``base`` constructor in your new ``derived`` constructor.

Comment: Oh, right it is complaining in the initialization list while trying to bind the rvalue `base::foo` to the const lvalue passed as argument to the `base` copy constructor...